# Why is Bumi silent in Season 4?

Tags: character, the-legend-of-korra

In season 1 - 3 of *The Legend of Korra*, Bumi's defining trait is that he won't shut up. When season 4 hits Bumi suddenly doesn't talk. He's in the background of shots and he even assists in a raid but he doesn't say a word. I'd understand a character just not having anything to do and having no reason to talk but Bumi is not only a habitual loudmouth but he's also a relatively active character in the last few episodes.

Did something happen there? Did his voice actor have conflicts or was the show unable to afford him due to budget cuts?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DemotedToExtra